# Flutter Firestore Query Nested Subcollections

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query subcollection in Firebase, but I always get an empty list...

This is my query:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('messages').where('idFrom', isEqualTo: userID).snapshots();
```

I know that I have subcollection with another subcollection here..

```
/messages/RWzG98s92mVTZniofez6YoYsNhA3-tT2Q16n1FMZoTNZQOejtWuJdCmD2/RWzG98s92mVTZniofez6YoYsNhA3-tT2Q16n1FMZoTNZQOejtWuJdCmD2/1579394957103
```

And my question is how to query these types of models?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Firstore queries are always shallow, you have to build the path to the subcollection to query.

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection('messages')
    .document(...)   // ID of the nested document
    .collection(...).  // ID of the nested subcollection
    .where('idFrom', isEqualTo: userID);
```

There is no way to avoid giving those nested IDs.  If you can't identify the full path of the subcollection to query, you won't be able to access its documents.