# Flutter How get All SubCollection From Firebase? I need AllDocument and All Collection

Tags: firebase, flutter, collections, google-cloud-firestore, document

```
 Future<void>  typeProduct (String currentUser) async {
    await databaseReference.collection('products').getDocuments().then((QuerySnapshot snapShot){
      _type=snapShot.documents;
      _type.forEach((data){
        print(data.documentID);enter image description here
      });
    });
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Please make sure you search properly on StackOverflow before asking questions. It's very likely that an answer for your question already exists, as it seems to be the case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59811699/flutter-firestore-query-nested-subcollections

Answer (score 0):

```
final productsRef = Firestore.instance.collection(products);    
productsRef.getDocuments().then(( QuerySnapshot snapshot){
            snapshot.documents.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc){
                print(doc.data);
            });
        });
```

Comment: No data has been printed

Comment: yes because there are no documents in your product collection, you have created subcollection try this
productsRef.getDocuments().subcollectionname().getDocuments().then

Comment: sorry
productsRef.subcollectionname().getDocuments().then

Comment: successfully done ,Thank You